# What is the difference between frequent pattern mining, subspace clustering, and biclustering?

Tags: clustering, data-mining

I have seen the terms "frequent pattern mining", "subspace clustering", and "biclustering".  They all pertain to finding clusters using subsets of the data attributes.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of the difference is the communities that use them.

Biclustering comes usually from biology, gene expression levels and such. The patterns they look for have typical characteristics, and they are usually mostly interested in trends (co-expression), not the actual numerical values.

To pattern mining, everything is a pattern, so of course they can do biclustering, too. All you need to solve is the complexity and the definition of what is an interesting pattern... They're special... the issue here is, they may easily miss patterns that are *too frequent* since these may trigger a "triviality" threshold. And other, more rare patterns, may in turn be considered random and dropped. It's hard to strike the right balance of not discarding the patterns you are interested in, and not producing way too many patterns to be usable (since at the end, everything is a pattern ...).

Subspace clustering is the data mining view. It should come along with thoughts about how to implement this *efficiently* in a large data base context. They often aren't as sophisticated as the pattern mining methods, but should be so fast that you can just give them a try, and see if they find anything useful. Maybe they do, maybe the don't - there is always a chance that there is nothing to find.

Comment: I used to think that [frequent pattern mining](http://adrem.ua.ac.be/~goethals/software/survey.pdf) has to do with association rules and frequent item sets, two topics that are in close connection with the data mining approach too.

Comment: Yes, there of course is a lot of overlap. Frequent Pattern Mining probably was triggered by the classic APRIORI algorithm, from the data mining community.
Still, it has split into a separate community, using different terminology and goals and often misunderstanding each other and looking down on the others ("you are doing it all wrong"). Which is very unfortunate for science.